# window.scroll not working with angular 11 and material

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I have this code in "Angular 11":

app.component.html:

```
<div class="app-container">

    <mat-toolbar >
  
    </mat-toolbar>
  
    <mat-sidenav-container >
      <mat-sidenav role="navigation">
        <mat-nav-list>
          <!-- <a mat-list-item routerLink="." *ngFor="let nav of fillerNav">{{ nav }}</a> -->
    
      </mat-sidenav>
      <mat-sidenav-content role="main">
  
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  
      </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
  </div>
```

And I want the page to be scrolled to top when navigate from page to other.
I have tried many.

first solution:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' })
```

Second solution:
In app.component.html

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)" ></router-outlet>
```

Then in app.component.ts

```
onActivate(event) {
    window.scroll(0,0);
    //or document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    //or document.querySelector('body').scrollTo(0,0)
    ...
}
```

nothing worked, How can I do this? any help?

Comment: You have tried "many". For example what?

Comment: I update my question.

Comment: You don't want to scroll the window, you want to scroll `mat-sidenav-content`, it uses an overflow to simulate a full page. [See this github comment](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4280#issuecomment-300703342).

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn that's it. You saved my time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to scroll the `mat-sidenav-content`. The window itself is already at `0` when using this component, as the component uses a full viewport height with overflow to make it look like the page is scrolling. There is an existing [github issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4280) asking for a feature for this.

You can place this in your app component to fix the issue:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events
    // For newer versions or rxjs use a pipe on the filter:
    // .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .subscribe(() => {
      document.querySelector('.mat-sidenav-content').scrollTop = 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: Ideally, the document query should be replaced with a @ViewChild reference.

Answer (score 1):

If at navigation don't want to scroll to the top and manually want to scroll by clicking on a button below things can be considered.

```
window.scroll(0,0);
    //or document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    //or document.querySelector('body').scrollTo(0,0)
```

this is not working as it is always at value 0, as angular creating its own viewport to render a different component inside

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

So better to target the immediate parent class or material tag

```
document.querySelector('your class name or material tag name').scrollTop = 0;
```

also, check if your parent element has the correct height style property

```
height:100%
```